# Paste from clipboard

Tags: jquery, clipboard, paste

How can I paste from clipboard using jQuery ?

Comment: Generally speaking, unless you're asking questions related to DOM traversal/manipulation, jQuery is probably not what you mean to ask about. Apart from plugins that wrap common JavaScript functionality into the jQuery namespace, there is quite a lot that jQuery doesn't do, and if there's nothing remotely related in the API documentation (http://api.jquery.com) you're probably discussing JavaScript.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can do this using javascript. Since clipboard data is part of the operating system your javascript code ill not be able to access that.

Comment: That's not entirely true. All of the major browser engines allow accessing clipboard data under certain conditions (WebKit and Trident [and Presto, I believe but can't say for sure] during paste/dragdrop events, Gecko with non-default security settings). Not that any of that solves the question asked.

Comment: It is not possible for all browsers and oses. Only by the flash plugin.

Comment: IMO never try to read data from user's clipboard in a web application.

Answer (score 1):

There is a very good JS / Flash library for this:

[Zero Clipboard](http://zeroclipboard.org/)

Its currently the only libaray which handles the latest flash plugin 10 as well!

Comment: ZeroClipboard only copies. No paste support.

Answer (score 1):

It may be possible in some browsers/environments using `document.execCommand`, but shouldn't be relied on and you're better off finding another solution.

For posterity:

```
document.execCommand('paste', false, null);
```