# Paste content in a DIV

Tags: javascript

The way to paste text or image to a DIV (like input) is to click that DIV and do the paste comment, which is CTRL + V usually.

Now, my question would be, is it possible with Javascript to paste a text or image to a DIV even the DIV (or input) even if that DIV is not selected?

Update:

```
<div contenteditable="true" id="pasteCapture" style="height: 100px; width: 100px; " onpaste='handlepaste(this, event)'></div> 
   <script>
        function getfocus(){
            document.getElementById('pasteCapture').focus()
        }
  </script>
```

So far this is what I have done. When the div is selected and paste is made, no problem. However, my requirement is that this DIV should get the paste item even its not selected on the page.

Reason for this is I will make this div hidden.

Comment: It's advisable that you show us what you tried so far (like pasting it to the selected div)

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4517053/paste-from-clipboard I think

Comment: @ultraviol3tlux I don't think that's a duplicate! he want to copy/past the selected content of his own page!

Comment: @ultraviol3tlux My question would not to access the clipboard, as not only that its browser dependent, its OS-dependent also in some cases. So my approach would be a have a hidden div that will get the pasted data which in a typical web app a div with contenteditable when clicked it can get the pasted data and create a child node for this matter.

Comment: Fair enough, my mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly you want to intercept a paste event and redirect the paste into a hidden div. I can do some of that:

*HTML*

```
Paste Stuff Here: <input id='pasteCapture' type='text'></input>
<div contenteditable="true" id="pasteRedirect" style="height: 100px; width: 100px; " >    
</div> 
<button 
  onclick=" document.getElementById('pasteRedirect').style.display = 'block';"
>Show Div</button>
```

*SCRIPT*

```
function handlePaste(e) {
    document.getElementById('pasteRedirect').style.display = 'block';
    document.getElementById('pasteRedirect').focus();
    e.srcElement = document.getElementById("pasteCapture");
    setTimeout( function() { 
        document.getElementById('pasteRedirect').style.display = 'none';
    }, 0 );
}

document.getElementById("pasteCapture").addEventListener("paste", handlePaste, false);
```

([Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SpaceDog/T9L99/))

If you paste into the input box there it get's caught and redirected to the DIV. I'm tried to get this to work across the whole page, or inside a container div but it doesn't -- looks like only some elements trigger the paste event.

Similarly it doesn't work when the DIV is hidden, so it needs to unhide the DIV then use a timeout to rehide it after the paste is complete.

I'm not sure if you can make that work for what you want to do.

Comment: Yeah, I can't think of a good way round that -- I considered putting an editable DIV over the whole page but that'll break all your other interactions. You could make the entire page editable and try and trap and disallow anything that's not a paste. Can you tell us *why* you want to do this -- maybe there's a different way to achieve the same functionality.